# How to create a generic List with a dynamic object type

Tags: c#, generics, list, dynamic

I want to create a generic list of the Type object.

I have ...

```
Type type = typeof(Foo);
object model = GetModel();
```

Now I want to create a `new List<Foo>((Foo)model)`

Is this possible in C#?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Type listT = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new[]{type});
object list = Activator.CreateInstance(listT);
```