# Extension method to Exception requiring dynamic generic type

Tags: c#, wcf, generics, exception

This question has been asked in different ways before, but the answers don't help me, because (1) I don't have control over the built-in `Exception` classes, and (2) `Activator.CreateInstance()` returns an object/instance, where I need a true dynamic type.

I'm trying to create an extension method that allows me to throw a `FaultException` out of my WCF service, based off the exception I catch.  For example:

```
try {
    ...
}
catch (ArgumentNullException exc) {
    throw new FaultException<ArgumentNullException>(exc);
}
```

is straight-forward.  But if I want to extend this in a general way, I'd use an extension class, like:

```
try {
    ...
}
catch (Exception exc) {
    exc.ThrowFaultException();
}
```

Where I get hung up, of course, is the implementation of the extension method:

```
public static void ThrowFaultException(this Exception exc) {

    //  Gives me the correct type...
    Type exceptionType = exc.GetType();

    //  But how the heck do I use it?
    throw new FaultException<???>(exc);
}
```

The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545807/instructing-a-generic-to-return-an-object-of-a-dynamic-type) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712732/how-to-create-a-generic-list-with-a-dynamic-object-type) don't help.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why can't you cast the return from `Activator.CreateInstance()` to `Exception`?  It will still get thrown as its actual type, no?

Comment: It's a good idea to throw exception from custom code and not from some generalized method. This would help VS.Net and other code analyzers (your peers included) to detect unreachable code and related issues.

Comment: BR/DP>  What I found when I tested that solution was that the caller caught the exception under the general catch (Exception exc){} handler, not the handler for FaultException<ArgumentException>

Comment: DK>  Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: James B> It's just general consideration, not directly related to the question... Imagine that later on a junior developer adds logging at the end of each exception handling. In your first code snippet with "throw" being right there, compiler will warn him right away that Log.LogError() call can not be placed after the throw statement since it will be unreachable; in fact it's unlikely that developer would even try to do it. In the situation with 2nd snippet it's more obscure for developer and there is no help from compiler. HTH.

Comment: I see what you're saying... I'd like to think that seeing a call that says 'throw an exception' would be enough to keep a developer from putting code afterwords, but you're right, the compiler definitely can't warn anyone who does so.  And it isn't as clear as explicitly throwing the exception.  I'll have to consider whether avoiding these issues is worth typing "throw new FaultException<ArgumentException>(new ArgumentException("Bad Argument!"));" for every exception is better.  Honestly, I'm inclined to say that exc.ThrowFaultException() is clearer!  But I see what you're saying.

Comment: Furthermore, what this gives me is the ability to handle every exception coming from lower down in a single catch{..}.  If I want to explicitly throw each exception, I have to catch each exception individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void ThrowFaultException<TException>(this TException ex) where TException : System.Exception
{
    throw new FaultException<TException>(ex);
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly!!  Exactly what I wanted : )

Comment: I constantly forget the beauty of generics!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to cast the object returned by Activator.CreateInstance to FaultException<?> to throw it. Casting it to Exception is enough:

```
var type = typeof(FaultException<>).MakeGenericType(exc.GetType());

throw (Exception)Activator.CreateInstance(type, exc);
```

---

I wouldn't throw the exception in `ThrowFaultException` though:

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw e.WrapInFaultException();
}

public static Exception WrapInFaultException(this Exception e)
{
    var type = typeof(FaultException<>).MakeGenericType(e.GetType());

    return (Exception)Activator.CreateInstance(type, e);
}
```

Comment: I was just thinking about posting this, but how would he pass exc as a parameter to the constructor of the FaultException? Does CreateInstance allow for this?

Comment: @Pandincus: I haven't tested it, but I believe the call to [Activator.CreateInstance(Type, Object\[\])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx) shown above should work as-is.

Comment: Nevermind, I see you edited your answer for that. Neat trick!

Comment: If I do that the client catches a general exception, not a FaultException<ArgumentException> : (

Answer (score 1):

```
   public static void ThrowFaultException(this Exception exc)
    {
        //  Gives me the correct type...
        Type exceptionType = exc.GetType();
        var  genericType = typeof(FaultException<>).MakeGenericType(exceptionType);
        //  But how the heck do I use it?
        throw (Exception)Activator.CreateInstance(genericType, exc);
    }
```