# Extension for conditional generic exception throwing

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I wanted to write an extension method that would **generate** and **thow** generic exception when some condition met. I came up with this code:

```
internal static TSource ConditionalThrow<TSource, TException>(this TSource source, Func<TSource, bool> throwCondition, TException exception, params object[] arguments) where TException : Exception
{
    if (throwCondition(source))
    {
        throw CreateInstance(exception.GetType(), arguments) as Exception;
    }
    else
    {
        return source;
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that user must actually initialize `exception` argument himself, so it can be simplified to:

```
internal static TSource ConditionalThrow<TSource, TException>(this TSource source, Func<TSource, bool> throwCondition, TException exception) where TException : Exception
{
    if (throwCondition(source))
    {
        throw exception;
    }
    else
    {
        return source;
    }
}
```

But I would like that extension would generate the error. A thought was to pass `Type` instead of `TException`, but then I cannot limit it to be `Exception` type.

```
internal static TSource ConditionalThrow<TSource>(this TSource source, Func<TSource, bool> throwCondition, Type exception)
{
    if (throwCondition(source))
    {
        throw CreateInstance(exception, arguments) as Exception;
    }
    else
    {
        return source;
    }
}
```

Can I actually achieve that extension would **generate** and **thow** generic exception?

I looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348838/extension-method-to-exception-requiring-dynamic-generic-type), but had no success.

Comment: It's not very clear what your problem is. Obviously, just *remove* the superfluous `exception` argument and you are good to go. The type is shall be passed in as a generic argument *only*.

Comment: But then I need to use `source.ConditionalThrow<TSource, TException>` everywhere, which looks so redundant..

Comment: Btw. what's so wrong about a plain `if (…) throw …;`?

Comment: Huh, totally missed you were returning `source`; hence want using it in some fluent-style API. Ignore my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's obvious that specifying both the type of the source and of the exception is better design, allowing for generic type contraints to be applied. Then to remove the necessity to specify both `TSource` and `TException` explicitly, you can decompose `ConditionalThrow` into two methods like this:

```
internal static void Throw<TException>(this bool condition, params object[] args) where TException : Exception
{
    if (condition) throw (Exception)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TException), args);
}

internal static bool If<TSource>(this TSource source, Func<TSource,bool> condition)
{
    return condition(source);
}
```

Then the usage would be like this:

```
10.If(x => x>0).Throw<Exception>();
```

However, this **does not** allow passing `source` back from `Throw`. As the OP correctly suggested, a workaround here is to wrap the call with another method that would ensure `source` is returned:

```
internal static TSource Do<TSource> (this TSource source, Action<TSource> action)
{ 
    action(source); 
    return source; 
}

int a = 10.Do(s => s.If(x => x>0).Throw<Exception>()) + 1;
```

Another option is to decompose the *instatiation* of the exception into a conditonally-executed delegate, like this:

```
internal static TSource ThrowIf<TSource>(this TSource source, Func<TSource,bool> condition, Func<Exception> buildException)
{
    if (condition(source))
        throw buildException();
    else
        return source;
}
```

Then the usage would be like this:

```
int a = 10.ThrowIf(x => x>0, () => new Exception()) + 1;
```

While this requires one more `() =>` lambda construct, the `source` **may be returned** in case of no-throw, and there's no need for an extra wrapping like in the former case.

A big advantage of the second approach is that **both exception instantiation and exception arguments' evaluation is lazy-evaluated**, i.e. only in case the exception is really supposed to be thrown. This *may* be a serious positive memory and performance factor, eliminating side-effects in non-exception code paths.

Comment: Then second example cunstructs exception on client side and throws at extension. Prity much my example number one, just with some extra code.

Comment: @DovydasSopa Your example #1 leads to *duplicate* instantiation. In my case the exception is constructed if and only if it is to be thrown. And the same is true for the evaluation of arguments, which is a big difference.

Comment: Oh yea, my bad. Example #2, not #1.

Comment: @DovydasSope Even though my solution prevents unnecessary instantiation and argument evaluation. That's a serious difference.

Comment: Then I could simply wrap it up in one more extension like `internal static T Do<T> (this T source, Action<T> action) { action (source); return source; }` and I would get the same object after validation.

Comment: @DovydasSopa You mean my first version? Likely, yes. However, I consider my second version is the best solution.

Comment: Yes, wrapping first version with another extension. Maybe update your first example with that as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99208/discussion-between-ondrej-tucny-and-dovydas-sopa).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, like using this:

#### First option (no compiler time validation for exeception type)

```
internal static TSource ConditionalThrow<TSource>(this TSource source, Func<TSource, bool> throwCondition, Type exceptionType, params object[] arguments)
{
    if (!typeof(Exception).IsAssignableFrom(exceptionType))
        throw new ArgumentException("exceptionType is not an Exception");
    if (throwCondition(source))
        throw Activator.CreateInstance(exceptionType, arguments) as Exception;
    return source;
}
```

#### Second option  (with compiler time validation for exeception type)

```
internal static TSource ConditionalThrow<TSource>(this TSource source, Func<TSource, bool> throwCondition, Func<Exception> exeptionBuilder)
{
    if (throwCondition(source))
        throw exeptionBuilder();
    return source;
}
```

Lets use the sample classes to test our solution

```
public class Temp
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyException : Exception
{
    public MyException(string name, string age)
        : base($"Name: {name} and Age: {age}")
    { }

    public MyException()
        : base("No parameter")
    { }
}
```

#### Testing the first option

```
try
{
    new Temp().ConditionalThrow(t => true, typeof(MyException), "Alberto", "25");
}
catch (MyException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
try
{
    new Temp().ConditionalThrow(t => true, typeof(MyException));
}
catch (MyException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}      
try
{
    new Temp().ConditionalThrow(t => true, typeof(string));
}
catch (ArgumentException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

#### Output for first option

> Name: Alberto and Age: 25
>
> No parameter
>
> exceptionType is not an Exception

Working sample: https://dotnetfiddle.net/brIjq9

#### Testing the second option

```
try
{
    new Temp().ConditionalThrow(t => true, () => new MyException("Alberto", "25"));
}
catch (MyException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
try
{
    new Temp().ConditionalThrow(t => true, () => new MyException());
}
catch (MyException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

#### Output for second option

> Name: Alberto and Age: 25
>
> No parameter

Working sample: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8ZQiIc

Comment: That looks nice, just wouldn't be perfect for using. Would need to use `source.ConditionalThrow<TSource, TException>` everywhere..

Comment: @DovydasSopa changed!

Comment: But with this changed you fall into last example I gave on my question - you cannot limit that user would pass **only** `Exception` type.

Comment: Try exchanging `typeof (MyException)` with something that is not `Exception`, like: `typeof (string)`. You will still cach exception, but it won't be the one you just threw. You woull cach either failed `CreateInstance` or you would `thow null`.

Comment: @DovydasSopa I got it, I will change that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99192/discussion-between-alberto-monteiro-and-dovydas-sopa).

Comment: @DovydasSopa I changed the answer

Comment: Then the exception is actually constructed on client side and thrown at extensions. Prity much my example number one, just with some extra code.

Comment: @DovydasSopa let chat

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `new()` generic constraint so you can create the exception in the method. The downside is that you *have* to specify the generic parameters, they cannot be inferred.

```
internal static TSource ConditionalThrow<TSource, TException>(this TSource source, Func<TSource, bool> throwCondition)
    where TException : Exception, new()
{
    if (throwCondition(source)) {
        throw new TException();
    } else {
        return source;
    }
}
```

Or you can use your current method which creates the exception yourself, but specify the type through the generic argument instead of a Type parameter.

```
internal static TSource ConditionalThrow<TSource, TException>(this TSource source, Func<TSource, bool> throwCondition)
    where TException : Exception
{
    if (throwCondition(source)) {
        throw CreateInstance(typeof(TException), arguments) as Exception;
    } else {
        return source;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Alberto Monteiro offered this at the begining, but that wouldn't be perfect for using. Would need to use `source.ConditionalThrow<TSource, TException>` everywhere..